# Confused by default permissions of SQL User for Certificate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, permissions, certificate, signing

I'm confused by following behaviour: I have an MS SQL Server Instance with two databases `DB_A`, `DB_B` and logins `own_dba` and `own_dbb` which are users and members of the `db_owner` role of their respective database. They don't have any permissions on the other respective database.

Now, for testing reasons I want `own_dba` to call a view on `DB_B` by executing a stored procedure `sp_dba`. I want this to happen by using module signing. I basically followed instructions found here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86424/sql-server-chain-permission/86437#86437tsql

What I did (by using a SysAdmin account) was

```
USE DB_B

CREATE CERTIFICATE Acc_DBB_Cert   
   ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'MySuperPwd!'  
   WITH SUBJECT = 'Certificate to access DB_B.',   
   EXPIRY_DATE = '20201031';  
GO

CREATE USER Acc_Dbb
    FROM CERTIFICATE Acc_DBB_Cert
GO

BACKUP CERTIFICATE Acc_DBB_Cert TO FILE = 'd:\MyCertFolder\Acc_DBB_Cert'
    WITH PRIVATE KEY ( FILE = 'd:\MyCertFolder\Acc_DBB_Cert_Key' ,   
    DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'MySuperPwd!',
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'MySuperPwd!' );  
GO

USE DB_A

CREATE CERTIFICATE Acc_DBA_Cert FROM FILE = 'd:\MyCertFolder\Acc_DBB_Cert'  
    WITH PRIVATE KEY ( FILE = 'd:\MyCertFolder\Acc_DBB_Cert_Key' ,   
                       DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'MySuperPwd!',
                       ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'MySuperPwd!');
GO

ADD SIGNATURE TO [dbo].[sp_dba]
    BY CERTIFICATE Acc_DBB_Cert WITH PASSWORD = 'MySuperPwd!'
GO
```

And what shall I say, it works perfectly. I can login as `own_dba`, execute `sp_dba` (which basically is only a `SELECT` statement on some view in `DB_B`) and it shows me the contents of the view.

What makes me wonder is that in the code above I forgot to grant any permissions to the user `Acc_Dbb` at all, but it works fine. As far, as I found informations on the internet I'm supposed to grant adequate permissions to the user. Are there default permissions for user from certificates (with private keys)?

I thought, there might be a bug in the system. In my first attempt I already created the user `Acc_Dbb` and made him member of `db_owners`. But I droped this user after the first attempt. Also, in my here mentioned second attempt, the user is not marked as member of `db_owners` (or owner of `db_owners`)...

Thanks for any ideas on this matter!
Best regards!

Comment: Could be ownership chaining. What are the results of `SELECT SUSER_SNAME(owner_sid), name, is_db_chaining_on, is_trustworthy_on FROM sys.databases WHERE name IN(N'DB_A', N'DB_B');`.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your answer. No, neither tustworhtyness nor ownership chaining is activated. In fact, I found my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is easy: By default, the `public` role has `SELECT` permissions on all objects of a database (which is, in my opinion, an odd default setting). Hence, the user `Acc_DBB` (who is member of `public`) is allowed to do a `SELECT` on the view, but no `UPDATE` or `INSERT`.

Comment: The public role does not have `SELECT` permissions on all objects by default. If no `SELECT` permissions were granted at the object level, the permissions were granted at a higher level.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's how it is supposed to be. I will have a deeper look into the servers security settings.